# Passing React props from child to parent in fetch then block

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I want to pass props from child to parent. I get data from API request in the child class , but when I pass it to the Parent class using callbacks, it sends me empty array, although it is full when I check it in the Child class. I cannot find where the problem is. Any suggestions?
notice: I am using callback inside fetch().then block

This is the Parent class

```
class Parent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            listDataFromChild: null
        };
        this.getData = this.getData.bind(this);
    }

    getData(val){
        this.setState({listDataFromChild: val});
        console.log(val.length);
    }

    render() {
        return (

            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-2">
                    <TableSearchForm callbackFromParent = {this.getData}/>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-8">
                    <Table data = {this.state.listDataFromChild}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

and this is the Child class:

```
class Child extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.props = props;
        this.state = { value: '' };
        this.state = {data: []};
        this.makeRequest = this.makeRequest.bind(this);
    }

    makeRequest() {

var apirequest = fetch(API_URL , {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        arg1: 'val1',
        arg2: 'val2'
    })
}).then(function(response){
    return response.json() })
    .then( function (json) {
        result = json[0]["col1"];
        var length = result.length
        console.log("length is: " + length);
    .then(this.props.callbackFromParent(result));
}
```

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `then(a)` and `then(a())` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

`.then(this.props.callbackFromParent(result));`

`then` of promise expect a function but you are calling the function inside `then`, which means you are passing returned value of that function to `then`. So pass a function to `then` instead like this

```
  .then(function(response){
    return response.json() 
  }).then( function (json) {
        result = json[0]["col1"];
        return result;
  }).then((result) => {
        this.props.callbackFromParent(result)
  });
```

Comment: This is not enough, context is lost.

Answer (score 0):

it is better to do this

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.props = props;

        this.state = {
            data: [] , 
            value:[]
         };
        this.makeRequest = this.makeRequest.bind(this);
    }
```

instead  of this

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.props = props;
        this.state = { value: '' };
        this.state = {data: []};
        this.makeRequest = this.makeRequest.bind(this);
    }
```